# How do I remove content from a modal-body upon closing the modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

My goal is to display a fresh modal every time it is opened. Currently, that is only true when the modal window is first displayed after refreshing the page. For the subsequent closing/opening of the modal, it just appends the current content to the end of the previous content, which is still displayed.

It may be worth noting that with this particular configuration of the countless efforts tried, I get an

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

in my Javascript console for the line

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

but I'm not sure why. The jQuery library (3.2.1) is initialized for the script type it's being used with after all. Any clue?

```
<!-- Form -->
<form onsubmit="return false">

  <!-- Heading -->
  <h3 class="dark-grey-text text-center">
    <strong>Calculate your payment:</strong>
  </h3>
  <hr>

  <div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-money prefix grey-text"></i>
    <input type="text" id="income" class="form-control">
    <label for="income">Your income</label>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-pink" onclick="calculator()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Calculate</button>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function calculator() {
        let payment = ((document.getElementById("income").value - 18210)*0.1)/12;
        payment = Math.round(payment);
        if (payment <= 0) {
          $('.modal-body').append("$0 per month.");
        }
        else {
          $('.modal-body').append(payment + " or less per month.");
        }
       }
    </script>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">You should be paying:</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="test" class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Clear content from modal -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $('.modal-body').clear();
        });
      });
    </script>
    <hr>
    <label class="grey-text">* This is just an estimate. Please call for a quote.</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

</form>
<!-- Form -->
```

Comment: Use `.text` instead of `.append`

Comment: `$` is probably undefined because you have jquery below where you use it on the page, so it's not loaded yet. Put your `<script>` stuff below your call to jQuery.

Comment: @BenWest I hate that it was that easy lol. Thanks a lot, Ben! You're the man.

Comment: @D_N Nailed it. Thanks, D_N!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.html` or `.text` instead of `.append`

```
if (payment <= 0) {
  $('.modal-body').text("$0 per month.");
}
else {
  $('.modal-body').text(payment + " or less per month.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Form -->
            <form onsubmit="return false">

              <!-- Heading -->
              <h3 class="dark-grey-text text-center">
                <strong>Calculate your payment:</strong>
              </h3>
              <hr>

              <div class="md-form">
                <i class="fa fa-money prefix grey-text"></i>
                <input type="text" id="income" class="form-control">
                <label for="income">Your income</label>
              </div>

              <div class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-pink" onclick="calculator()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Calculate</button>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                  function calculator() {
                    let payment = ((document.getElementById("income").value - 18210)*0.1)/12;
                    payment = Math.round(payment);
                    if (payment <= 0) {
                      $('.modal-body').text("$0 per month.");
                    }
                    else {
                      $('.modal-body').text(payment + " or less per month.");
                    }
                  }
                </script>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">You should be paying:</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="test" class="modal-body">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Clear content from modal -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                      $('.modal-body').clear();
                    });
                  });
                </script>
                <hr>
                <label class="grey-text">* This is just an estimate. Please call for a quote.</label>
                </fieldset>
              </div>

            </form>
            <!-- Form -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jon! This works swimmingly as does Ben's .text suggestion. With these variations, a separate clearing function isn't needed at all, which I thought felt unnatural to begin with..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `$('modal-body').empty()` instead of `clear`